# Boot error on Windows "Couldn't delete target"

Tags: windows, clojure, clojurescript, boot-clj

Well, basically I'm facing a problem just on Windows, when I run "boot run dev" on macOS or Linux, it works perfectly, but on Windows, the dream is over, the boot starts but get an error soon as it starts, this is my build.boot:

```
(set-env!
  :source-paths #{"src"}
  :resource-paths #{"src" "resources"}
  :dependencies '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0" :scope "provided"]
                  [adzerk/boot-cljs "2.1.4" :scope "test"]
                  [adzerk/boot-reload "0.5.2" :scope "test"]
                  [pandeiro/boot-http "0.8.3" :scope "test"]
                  [nightlight "RELEASE"]
                  [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.946"]
                  [rum "0.10.8"]
                  [org.roman01la/cljss "1.5.13"]
                  [org.clojure/core.async "0.4.474"]
                  [io.replikativ/konserve "0.4.11"]
                  [ring/ring-core "1.6.3"]
                  [bidi "2.1.2"]
                  [congomongo "0.5.0"]
                  [cljs-http "0.1.44"]
                  [http-kit "2.2.0"]
                  [com.hypirion/clj-xchart "0.2.0"]])

(require
  '[adzerk.boot-cljs :refer [cljs]]
  '[adzerk.boot-reload :refer [reload]]
  '[pandeiro.boot-http :refer [serve]]
  '[nightlight.boot :refer [nightlight sandbox]])

(task-options!    
  aot {:namespace   #{'brad.server}}    
  pom {:project     'brad        
       :version     "0.1.0"         
       :description "FIXME: write description"         
       :url         "http://example/FIXME"         
       :scm         {:url "https://github.com/yourname/brad"}         
       :license     {"Eclipse Public License"                       
                     "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}}    
  jar {:main        'brad.server         
       :file        "brad.jar"}
  cljs {:ids #{"brad/admins" "brad/fisicos"}})


(deftask dev []
  (comp
    (watch)
    (reload :asset-path "brad"
            :cljs-asset-path ".")
    (sandbox :file "java.policy")
    (cljs :source-map true 
          :optimizations :none)
    (target)))

(deftask run []
  (comp
    (serve :dir "target/brad" :port 3000)
    (dev)
    (nightlight :port 4000 :url "http://localhost:3000")))

(deftask build []  
  (comp    
    (cljs :optimizations :advanced          
          :compiler-options {:fn-invoke-direct true})    
    (aot)    
    (pom)    
    (uber)    
    (jar)    
    (target)))
```

Sorry about the extensive code, I think that maybe the problem is with some permission that I didn't give, I was trying to run boot on git bash, then I tried on windows powershell, the same error was ocurred, please, help me, and I'm sorry about my english.

Comment: Have you tried to Run as administrator the git bash / powershell? Have you tried manually deleting the target directory?

Comment: Yes, the target was created by boot, even with the error, before I run again I deleted the target folder manually, but the same error occurred and other target was created. I tried to run as administrator, even with another account of windows.

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues on Windows, please try on Windows 10.